# Laravel mass update a date column by adding a value from other column of same row

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, laravel-query-builder

I have a following MySQL table:

| id | days_remaining | final_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-10-01 |
| 2 | 10 | 2023-10-01 |

I'm trying to mass update the `final_date` column. The resulting value of this column is a fixed date value eg: `2023-10-10` plus the `days_remaining` added into it.

**This is the resulting table:**

| id | days_remaining | final_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-10-14 |
| 2 | 10 | 2023-10-20 |

**What I was trying, but no success:**

```
DB::table('my_table')
    ->update([
        'final_date' => Carbon::parse('2023-10-10')->addDays(DB::raw('days_remaining'))->toDateString()
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use DB Facade:

```php
DB::table('my_table')
    ->update([
        'final_date' => DB::raw('DATE_ADD("2023-10-10", INTERVAL `days_remaining` DAY)')
    ])
```

Or Elequont:

```php
YourModel::update([
        'final_date' => DB::raw('DATE_ADD("2023-10-10", INTERVAL `days_remaining` DAY)')
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the right direction. I edited your answer to add a hard coded date (2023-10-10) to ```'final_date' => DB::raw('DATE_ADD("2023-10-10", INTERVAL `days_remaining` DAY)') ```